# Nginx returns 403 Forbidden on certain api/* routes occasionally only

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, node.js

I use Nginx as a reverse proxy for node.js server and I have following routes, that start with:

```
- /api/...
- /auth/...
```

If I open my site in incognito mode and try to submit a form to persists it to sever using route `'/api/user'` I get 403 Forbidden. I am confused that on my local machine with server running with vagrant and nginx I never had an issue like this. In production I also managed to successfully submit the form a few times on the above mentioned route but never in incognito mode.

I proxy only certain routes to nodejs like this:

```
location ~ ^/(api|user|auth|socket.io-client|sitemap.xml) {
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header   Host                   $http_host;
  proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_pass_header  X-CSRFToken;
  add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
  sendfile  off;
  proxy_pass         http://nodejs_upstream;
}
```

I checked that route `'/api/user'` is being correctly caught by the above block so maybe it relates to nodejs server permissions but I am stuck at that point. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you studied which entity actually sends the 403 error code? To me it looks likely that your node.js application sends that response for some reason, and you should study its logs.

Comment: X-XSRF-TOKEN is missing from Request Headers - so nodejs sends back 403. Currently trying to figure out why ssl implementation removes X-XSRF-TOKEN token